# Как делать escape?

Tags: php, orm, activerecord

Каким образом делается эскейпинг входящих post-данных в orm phpactiverecord. Это нужно делать своими силами или ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не понимаю при чем тут post данные, но в PHP ActiveRecord есть такая штука как `conditions`, если через них передавать данные то они автоматически будут проходить обработку, парочка примеров:

```
# fetch all the cheap books!
Book::all(array('conditions' => array('price < ?', 15.00)));
# sql => SELECT * FROM `books` WHERE price < 15.00

# fetch all lousy romance novels
Book::find('all', array('conditions' => array('genre = ?', 'Romance')));
# sql => SELECT * FROM `books` WHERE genre = 'Romance'

# fetch all books with these authors
Book::find('all', array('conditions' => array('author_id in (?)', array(1,2,3))));
# sql => SELECT * FROM `books` WHERE author_id in (1,2,3)

# fetch all lousy romance novels which are cheap
Book::all(array('conditions' => array('genre = ? AND price < ?', 'Romance', 15.00)));
# sql => SELECT * FROM `books` WHERE genre = 'Romance' AND price < 15.00
```

[Источник](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/projects/main/wiki/Finders)

Comment: Thank you, very much! I know.